# WPF DataGrid TwoWay Binding

Tags: wpf, xaml, data-binding

I have property `UserSet` which contains from `ObservableCollection<GridRow>`.
`GridRow` - my class, which contains 4 properties like this:

```
public int Id
{
    get { return id; }
    set
    {
        id = value;
        RaisePropertyChanged("Id");
    }
}
```

I populate UserSet, then Grid binds to it. When I change `id` field works setter `Id`. It sets right values.
But, after all changes, when I click other button my `UserSet` has not modified values. So I can't get updated Grid.
This is my XAML:

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding UsersSet, Mode=TwoWay}" AutoGenerateColumns="True">

</DataGrid>
```

Please help.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You could try and set the `UpdateSourceTrigger`:

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding UsersSet, 
                        Mode=TwoWay, 
                        UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" 
          AutoGenerateColumns="True">

</DataGrid>
```

Without knowing the rest of your code it is pretty hard to guess.

Comment: No problem that is what we are here for :)

Comment: @EbiDK Hi. May be not, but I'm not sure while this question was actual year ago...  Sorry.