# WPF DataGrid - Dynamic Two Way Binding to T instances in ObservableCollection<T>

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, data-binding, datagrid

Suppose I have a model (leaving out the full implementations of INotifyPropertyChanged for brevity):

```
public class MyModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    // ... 
}
```

with a view-model (also leaving out full implementations of INotify...):

```
public class MyViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged 
{ 
    public int SomethingUnrelatedToProblem { get; set; }
    // ... 
    public ObservableCollection<MyModel> MyModels { get; set; } 
}
```

a `MyView.xaml` containing a `DataGrid` (this is an excerpt):

`<DataGrid Name="MyModelDataGrid" ItemsSource="{Binding MyModels}"/>`

and lastly, the code-behind:

```
public class MyWindow : Window 
{
    public MyWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = MyViewModel();
    }
}
```

As it stands, this code will properly construct a `DataGrid` that successfully does the following:

- autogenerates columns based on the properties of `MyModel`
- displays each instance of 'MyModel' (with the corresponding values of its properties) as a row

However, any changes made to the `DataGrid` itself are not propagated *back* to the respective instances of `MyModel`.

I think (correct me if I'm wrong - I'm new to WPF/MVVM) that it is possible to achieve this by extending the `DataGrid` declaration in the `MyView.xaml` to include inner tags with the columns by specifying `Header="<MyModel.PropertyNameA" Text="{Binding PropertNameA}"`.

But! I would like this "cell-binding" to be done dynamically (just like the columns are auto-generated). The reason for this is that it's more extensible with respect to changes to `MyModel`, i.e. I then don't need to change both `MyModel` and `MyView.xaml` for additional properties.

Is this possible? If so, how can it be done?

Comment: Your `DataGrid` declaration seems inadequate, you can probably refer to this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10772320/wpf-datagrid-twoway-binding

Comment: If you edit the text of a cell and press the return key or tab out of the cell, the corresponding property of that `MyModel` instance will be updated. Why do you believe otherwise? Did you put a breakpoint in the setter in MyModel? It sounded like you were saying `{get; set;}` was just a stand-in for the actual INPC code in the properties, is that correct? Or are they really just `{get; set;}`? Is there more to your DataGrid in the XAML? Please provide a *complete* C#/XAML sample that reliably reproduces the issue. Include your INPC implementation, but omit any properties/methods not used.

Comment: Can you post your `DataGrid` xaml?

Comment: @VTChiew, @Tronald That IS the full `DataGrid` xaml, but see my next comment for context; within this scope, this question is resolved.

Comment: @EdPlunkett: Yes, I did omit the INPC code (for brevity). I also dropped breakpoints in those setters. After reading your comment, I went back and did this again to find that while the `OnPropertyChanged` was being fired for the first set, it was being _refired_. This was enough for me to realize that I failed to recognize a hidden interaction with another service. As such, this question is irrelevant.

Comment: @StarFox I was afraid it might be something weird. Good luck!